# Cannot fetch partial content from URL

Tags: python, http, python-requests

This is the URL: http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/Panasonic_HDC_TM_700_P_50i.m4v

the response from this URL has the Accept-Ranges header set to bytes but when i try to fetch a subset(bytes=1-2) of the response, it sends me the whole video with status code 200

Here is the python code i used

```py
import requests

url = 'http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/Panasonic_HDC_TM_700_P_50i.m4v'

headers = {'Range': 'bytes=1-2'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(len(response.content))
print(response.headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that requests in default operating mode (e.g. using only `.get()`) sends some additional HTTP headers - and the server then responds with whole content.

So to send only this specific header `Range`, see following example:

```py
import requests

url = (
    "http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/Panasonic_HDC_TM_700_P_50i.m4v"
)

headers = {
    "Range": "bytes=1-2",
}

with requests.session() as s:
    req = requests.Request("GET", url, headers=headers)
    prepped = req.prepare()
    resp = s.send(prepped)

    print(len(resp.content))
    print(resp.headers)
    print(resp.status_code)
```

Prints:

```
2

{
    "Date": "Mon, 14 Aug 2023 18:18:18 GMT",
    "Server": "Apache",
    "Upgrade": "h2",
    "Connection": "Upgrade, close",
    "Last-Modified": "Thu, 23 Mar 2017 21:44:11 GMT",
    "ETag": '"193100d-54b6cc707b215"',
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": "2",
    "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "Content-Range": "bytes 1-2/26415117",
    "Content-Type": "video/x-m4v",
}

206
```